# A property exists in the parent class, but can't be used from the child class

Tags: php

EDIT: SOLVED!

I have been working on my own framework lately. I have a controller class like this:

```
class Controller {
    private $model;

    public function __construct() {
        global $bean_db, $mv_name;

        if (file_exists(APP_PATH . 'models/' . $mv_name . '.php')) {
            require APP_PATH . 'models/' . $mv_name . '.php';

            $model_name = $mv_name . '_Model';
            $model = new $model_name;
            $this->model = $model;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in a specific controller file, I have code like this:

```
class Start_Controller extends Controller {
    function execute() {
        $this->model->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    }
}
```

As you may or may not expect, that did not work. I get an error message that the property named "model" does not exist. Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: At least accept ... one of the answers below

Comment: You don't need to edit for solved, just accept. Then everybody on SO can recognize this as an answered question.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers or add your own solution and accept it. That will mark the question as solved.

Comment: You really don't want to use global.  Especially not in an object. You should pass the values of $bean_db and $mv_name in as constructor arguments instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because a `private` variable is limited to this class *only* and not to any children.
You need `protected` for this case

Answer (score 1):

Make `model` `protected` rather than `private`.  That's an immediate solution, but you may also want to re-work how your controllers access their models.

Comment: I was thinking the whole time that "private" allows the property to be used in child classes. This is only a "first draft" later I will work on the refinements. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Private members are exclusive to the class in which they are declared.  They can't be accessed anywhere else, even in subclasses.

You can overcome this in one of two ways.

1. Make the private member protected
2. Provide a protected getter for the private member

Normally you'd do the former, but there are cases where the latter may be a more sensible approach (if, for example, you need read-only access to the member).